# Code does not evaluate in version 12.1 in a reasonable amount of time

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I just installed Mathematica version 12.1 on my desktop, and I have Mathematica version 11.3 on my laptop.

There's a line of code that runs fine (although it takes a while to evaluate) on my laptop, but runs "forever" on my desktop. I'm thinking maybe there's something that changed from 11.3 to 12.1 that's messing with things, but I don't get any error message, so in truth I'm not sure.

Below are the two lines that work on my laptop, but the second line fails on my desktop.

This works OK:

```
RhoTilde1 = 
  α/(2*Pi) C/x Log[Min[x^2 En^2, (1 - x)^2 En^2]/m^2] 
    HeavisideTheta[1 - x] HeavisideTheta[x - xm] /. {C -> 8/3, m -> 0.1};
A = RhoTilde1 /. {α -> 0.2, En -> 10, xm -> 0.01};
B = RhoTilde1 /. {α -> 0.3, En -> 1, xm -> 0.1};
c = RhoTilde1 /. {α -> 0.1, En -> 100, xm -> 0.001}; 
Show[
  Plot[A, {x, 0.01, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 15}}, PlotStyle -> Blue],
  Plot[B, {x, 0.1, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 15}}, PlotStyle -> Red],
  Plot[c, {x, 0.001, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 15}}, PlotStyle -> Black]]
```

This doesn't seem to evaluate in 12.1:

```
cInt = 
  Refine[
    Integrate[
      RhoTilde1 /. {α -> 0.1, En -> 100, xm -> 0.001, x -> x - y},
      {y, 0.001, x - 0.001}], 
    {0.001 < x < 1}]
```

I'd appreciate any pointers. Thanks!

UPDATE: Okay so the line just evaluated... after about 20 minutes. Any ideas why it took so long? It takes about 30 seconds on my laptop.

Comment: Well, do not mix precise and approximate numbers. After I replaced All approximate numbers like 0.1 to 1/10, 0.001 to 1/1000, etc.  (do this for all input), then computation on 12.1 takes about 30 seconds again.

Comment: Epic, thank you, this fixed it. Was totally unaware that that was bad practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following user18792 suggestion, I get

[image: result]

from

```
cInt =
  Refine[
    Integrate[
      RhoTilde1 /. {α -> 1/10, En -> 100, xm -> 1/1000, x -> x - y}, 
      {y, 1/1000, x - 1/1000}],
    {1/1000 < x < 1}]
```

in about a minute on an 11 year old iMac running 12.1.1.